# Use React hooks for file upload component

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple web app I'm trying to add context to.
I'm fairly certain I don't need redux, since state complexity is relatively minimal for this single page web app.  However, I'm struggling to get more advanced functions with hooks to render properly.

Specifically, when I upload files via the PaperDropzone component, function to check whether a file is already in the index array of files is not reading the proper state.  The function call always returns (-1).

I'm sure this is because my custom hook is missing something, I'm just not sure what.

**useGlobalState.js**

```
import React from "react";

/* Action types */
const SET_SIDEBAR = "SET_SIDEBAR";
const ADD_FILE_TO_INDEX = "ADD_FILE_TO_INDEX";

/* Define a context and reducer for managing global state. */
const initialState = {
  open: false,
  fileNames: [],
  files: []
};

const GlobalStateContext = React.createContext(initialState);

function globalStateReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_SIDEBAR":
      return { ...state, open: action.payload };
    case "ADD_FILE_TO_INDEX":
      return { ...state, fileNames: state.fileNames.concat(action.payload) };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

/* Export a component to prvide the context to its children */
export function MyProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(globalStateReducer, initialState);
  return (
    <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {children}
    </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

/* Default export is a custom hook that allows us to update state globally via a simple API*/
export default function useGlobalState() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useContext(GlobalStateContext);

  function setSidebar() {
    dispatch({ type: SET_SIDEBAR, payload: !state.open });
  }

  function addFileToIndex(fileName) {
    dispatch({ type: ADD_FILE_TO_INDEX, payload: fileName });
  }

  return { state, setSidebar, addFileToIndex };
}
```

and here is my child component...

**Dropzone.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import XLSX from "xlsx";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import RootRef from "@material-ui/core/RootRef";

// Custom Components
import useGlobalState from "../context/useGlobalState";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: { flexGrow: 1 },
  dropzonePaper: { minHeight: 300 }
}));

function isUploaded(fileName, fileArray) {
  return fileArray.indexOf(fileName) === -1 ? false : true;
}

export default function PaperDropzone(props) {
  const { state, addFileToIndex } = useGlobalState();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const currentFiles = state.fileNames;

  const onDrop = React.useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onabort = () => console.log("file reading was aborted");
      reader.onerror = () => console.log("file reading has failed");
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        addFileToIndex(file.name);
      };
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
  }, []);
  const {
    isDragActive,
    getRootProps,
    getInputProps,
    isDragReject,
    acceptedFiles,
    rejectedFiles
  } = useDropzone({ onDrop, accept: ".xlsx, .xls, .csv" });
  const { ref, ...rootProps } = getRootProps();

  return (
    <RootRef rootRef={ref}>
      <Paper className={classes.dropzonePaper} {...rootProps}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        {props.children}
      </Paper>
    </RootRef>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady). It provides hooks and drag&drop functionality with very little code on your part:

```js
import Uploady from "@rpldy/uploady";
import UploadDropZone from "@rpldy/upload-drop-zone";
 
const App = () => (
    <Uploady destination={destination}>
        <UploadDropZone onDragOverClassName="drag-over"
                        grouped={grouped}
                        maxGroupSize={groupSize}>
            <span>Drag&Drop File(s) Here</span>            
        </UploadDropZone>
    </Uploady>);
```